# stuck on Unity 3D Package Manager Error when trying to open any Unity project

Tags: unity-game-engine, package-managers

I have been facing this error for 5 months.

I have tried everything to fix it. Nothing's working. I have driven myself to near insanity trying to fix this problem.

Everything i try to boot up a Unity Project, this error shows up:

[i hate this image so much](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CJju.png)

PLEASE. IF YOU HAVE A SOLUTION, TELL ME.

Answer (score 4):

have you tried the following?

- **Firewall White-listing of the editor program**:

Go to windows firewall -> Advanced Settings -> Inbound rules - > Create new Rule-> type: program -> Complete path to the unity editor -> Allow Connections -> Give it a name -> Save.

- **Setting Environmental variables**:

HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY and UNITY_NOPROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1

​
Even if you already have a rule for Unity explicitly recreate it!

I hope this helps.

Comment: What do i put as the value for each of those variables?

Comment: Also do you have to have a proxy server for unity to work? I don't have a proxy server. If so, how do you get one?

Answer (score 2):

No clues don't worry there is solution...
First, go to Settings> Update & Security> Windows Security> Windows & Network protection>Windows Defender firewall> you have to turn off the firewall protection.

It will successfully helps out. Trust me it really do!

Answer (score 2):

Go to Settings --> Update and Security -->Select Windows Security Tab
-->Click 'Firewall and Network Protection' -->Select 'Advanced Settings'
-->Inbound Rules -->You will a rule Where Unity Editor will be set to block Right click on it and select properties
-->In dialogue box shown choose 'Allow the connection' and
then restart Unity Hub and create new project additional Templates will now be available.

Answer (score 0):

Does this problem also occur with a different project?

I could not open any project because of this "package manager error" and solved the issue by just closing all other running programs on my PC.